# Docker Build using an Assumed Role Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to build a docker image locally that copies an s3 file and sets it as the file to be executed by the container.

How can I reference the proper profile I'm needing for the S3 Bucket inside the docker file without using access keys?

dockerfile:

```
FROM onesysadmin/awscli:latest
RUN aws s3 cp s3://sample-bucket-dev-us-east-1/test_script.sh test_script.sh
RUN chmod 755 test_script.sh
CMD test_script.sh
```

.aws/credentials:

```
[master]
aws_access_key_id = ASIASF.......
aws_secret_access_key = 75opt1.......
aws_session_token = FwoGZXIvYXdzE......
aws_security_token = FwoGZXIvYXdzEFwoGZ......

[master-dev]
region = us-east-1
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/master-admin
source_profile = master
```

ie..I want to be able to use `master-dev` as the profile in my `docker build` command.

Comment: Have you read documentation like [How Amazon EKS works with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html)?  In EKS, you need an IAM role, then you need a Kubernetes service account with that IAM role, then your Kubernetes deployment needs to use that service account.  You also need a reasonably current version of the AWS SDKs.

Comment: That side of things I'm comfortable with, I'm just wondering the best way to actually build the image locally without having to store my personal AWS credentials in the image.

Comment: The readme at https://hub.docker.com/r/onesysadmin/awscli/ specifically shows how to mount a credentials file or credentials as environment variables at run time. Is there some part of this you are having an issue with?

Comment: I'm looking to pass credentials at build, not during the run. I think I'm close to what I desire with the buildkit, https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/, but trying to figure out how to use multiple aws profiles.

Comment: I updated the question & title to be much more accurate on my question and what I'm trying to achieve. My original question was unclear and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the docker [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/).

I'm on a mac and had to change my 'docker desktop' settings to `true` for experimental (Docker --> Preferences --> Docker Engine):

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

Then I changed my dockerfile:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM onesysadmin/awscli:latest
ARG PROFILE
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=$PROFILE
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials aws sts get-caller-identity
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials aws s3 cp s3://sample-bucket-dev-us-east-1/test_script.sh test_script.sh
RUN chmod 755 test_script.sh
CMD test_script.sh
```

And finally ran the build command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t testing --build-arg PROFILE=master-dev \
--secret id=aws,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .
```