# Docker Build-time Secrets with Layer Caching

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codeartifact

I have a Dockerfile that does a `pip install` of a package from an AWS code artifact. The install requires an auth token, so my current approach is to generate the dynamic/secret repo url in a build script and pass it into Docker as a build arg, which leads to lines like this in my Dockerfile:

```
ARG CORE_REPO_URL
ARG CORE_VERSION
RUN pip install -i $CORE_REPO_URL mylib_core==$CORE_VERSION
```

The use of ARGs in a `RUN` command cause that layer to never be cached, and therefore this part gets rebuilt every time even if the library version did not change.

Is there a better way to do this such that the layer cache would be used unless the `CORE_VERSION` changed?

Maybe I should be installing the `aws` tool chain in the image so the dynamic repo url can be generated in there in an earlier step (using the same command every time so it wouldn't require an ARG and would hopefully cache the layer)? One downside of this is having to put  AWS credentials in the image. I could maybe involve `docker secrets` to avoid that if that's the only solution though.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Did you change the approach? Facing a similar problem myself.

Comment: I have not implemented a better solution yet. Was hoping for more folks to chime in here but there must not be a lot of people running into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out for my use case of :

- Package in CA
- Multi account setup where you assume a role to get where you need.

Hopefully this will help someone else who finds this.

[Docker Build using an Assumed Role Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904241/docker-build-using-an-assumed-role-profile)

Remember to build with the buildkit

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
# This needs to go at the top of the file or it will break ^

# installing requirements NB, You can probably just take this image it's real small and depending on latest isn't the best, but idc only working on a poc.
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest AS dependencies
ARG PYTHONLIBS
ARG PROFILE
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=$PROFILE
COPY ./requirements.txt .
# NB I had this here as I was assuming a role you may not need it.
COPY ./config /root/.aws/config
RUN yum install -y pip
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials aws codeartifact login --tool pip --repository //rest of command
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target ${PYTHONLIBS}
```

Answer (score 5):

We've managed to work around this for private npm modules using docker/buildkit secrets:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,dst=/root/.npmrc npm install --ignore-scripts --no-audit
```

And when we run the docker build command:

```
docker buildx build --secret id=npmrc,src=$HOME/.npmrc .
```

When taking this approach, even if the token changes, the cache isn't invalidated.